# Outlook 2007 hyperlink does not display and the display field codes option is not there

Tags: microsoft-outlook, hyperlink, display-settings

I am trying to turn off the "Display Field Codes" in Outlook 2007 editor options, but my Outlook is not displaying this option!  I don't know why others can see it and I don't have this.

Meanwhile, my links show up with those darn brackets {www.google.com} etc. And I can't fix it without this button!

Answer (score 0):

Did you try pressing <kbd>ALT</kbd> + <kbd>F9</kbd>? This keyboard shortcut typically works for any version of Outlook and Word to toggle between Field Codes and their values.

Comment: Thanks, that does work.  I just wonder if there is a permanent fix.   I must have changed something in Outlook or another program to cause this to suddenly start happening, but I have no idea what it was.   I've already tried switching from using Chrome to using a new, clean install of Explorer, because someone said it could be browser related.

Comment: Is my fix not "sticking?" That is, do form fields still show up in new emails? I'd eat my hat if it had something to do with your browser, especially chrome.